# Pandas Dataframe Resample OHLC has wrong open price

Tags: python, pandas

I am unable to generate "accurate" OHLC data from tick data using pandas DataFrame.resample() ver 0.18.
Specifically I get a "future leak" at the open price of those bars where the price continues across an interval.

Reproduceable Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)
size=1000
df = pd.DataFrame(1.26 + np.random.rand(size)/100.0,index=pd.date_range('20160101 09:00:00',periods=size,freq='7s'),columns=['price'])
dfohlc = df.price.resample('1min').ohlc().ffill()
```

This is the series of randomly generate price ticks:

```
2016-01-01 09:00:00  1.261915
2016-01-01 09:00:07  1.266221
2016-01-01 09:00:14  1.264377
2016-01-01 09:00:21  1.267854
2016-01-01 09:00:28  1.267800
2016-01-01 09:00:35  1.262726
2016-01-01 09:00:42  1.262765
2016-01-01 09:00:49  1.268019
2016-01-01 09:00:56  1.269581   << this is the market price until 09.01:03
2016-01-01 09:01:03  1.268759   << this price should not be the open price at 09:01
...
```

The resample() generates these bars:

```
2016-01-01 09:00:00  1.261915  1.269581  1.261915  1.269581
2016-01-01 09:01:00  1.268759  1.268759  1.260138  1.260138
...
```

The open and close prices for the 1st OHLC bar at 09:00 are corrrect.

However the 2nd OHLC bar at 09:01:00 has the "wrong" open price 1.268759.  This price would not be visible until 09:01:03.  The "correct" price at the open was still 1.269581.

Is there any way to get the resample() function to generate the "correct" open price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting...

It appears the behavior is to group on time and take the first value in that grouped period as the open.

I imagine it makes sense to use the prior close as the opening bar, *except* for market open perhaps.

An easy fix to take the prior close as open is `df['open'] = df['close'].shift()`.

If you had a flag to indicate the opening bar of the market and you wish to use the first observed price as the open, then this would work:

```
df.loc[df['market_open_flag'] == False, 'open'] = df['close'].shift()
```

I'm not sure what the default behavior would be if there are no observed trades, e.g. illiquid stocks.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation; I was thinking along the same lines as a simple fix but needed confirmation.

Comment: Agree this solution makes sense except where there is a market open as is the case with equities.  For futures and fx the markets are (almost) continuous Sun-Fri.  

I guess the default behaviour for ohlc() should really be to take the value immediately before or at the time interval, and definitely not the next value that appears after the time interval has passed as that would be a source of a future leak ....